# Stripe payment with node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

My stack: 
Frontend: react,
[react-stripe module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout)
Backend: nodejs with Express 4.x

I've been following the examples on https://stripe.com/docs/charges

Heres my frontend code which gets triggered after the user clicks "Pay":

```
  onToken(token){
    console.log("Token " , token);
    $.post('/apicall', token, function(result){
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
```

And here's my server code that receives the data and should handle the test payment:

```
router.post('/payment/barf-complete', function(req, response, next){
  console.log(req.body);
  var stripeToken = req.body;

  var charge = stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1990, // amount in cents, again
    currency: "eur",
    source: stripeToken,
    description: "Example charge"
    }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
      // The card has been declined
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

I had to change `var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;` into `var stripeToken = request.body;` because the first variable declaration kept being undefined.

Now the issue is that I keep getting the following error on my server right after the payment got done in the frontend:

```
rawType: 'card_error',
code: 'invalid_number',
param: 'number',
message: 'The card object must have a value for \'number\'.',
```

I have never used a payment system before and the documentation doesn't provide any useful information for me -  :/

Any ideas what I might have missed?

**EDIT** Heres a console.log of request.body:

```
{ id: 'tok_123456789',
  object: 'token',
  'card[id]': 'card_123456789',
  'card[object]': 'card',
  'card[address_city]': '',
  'card[address_country]': '',
  'card[address_line1]': '',
  'card[address_line1_check]': '',
  'card[address_line2]': '',
  'card[address_state]': '',
  'card[address_zip]': '',
  'card[address_zip_check]': '',
  'card[brand]': 'Visa',
  'card[country]': 'US',
  'card[cvc_check]': 'pass',
  'card[dynamic_last4]': '',
  'card[exp_month]': '1',
  'card[exp_year]': '2017',
  'card[funding]': 'credit',
  'card[last4]': '4242',
  'card[name]': 'noa@mail.com',
  'card[tokenization_method]': '',
  client_ip: '12334567',
  created: '1457075159',
  email: 'noa@mail.com',
  livemode: 'false',
  type: 'card',
  used: 'false' }
```

Comment: does request.body.id work?

Comment: a stripe charge takes an object that has a key: `source` (as you have). The value corresponding to that key can either be the token (a string), or a card (an object). You're putting in `req.body`. `req.body` is always an object. Since it sees an object, it's expecting it to have the key: `number`

Comment: @cdbajorin so how would I need to change my code in order to make it work the stripe way

Comment: @MatthewArkin Sorry for the delay - I didn't get hands on my laptop yesterday night anymore - I will try your suggestion and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I have updated my Question with the request.body log. @MatthewArkin - logging the ID returns the tok number

Comment: so source should = req.body.id not req.body

Comment: I don't know whether It would be helpful to you or not, but I have created a node app for stripe payment which includes payment functionality and add card, so that customer don't have to enter card details again and again, here's the link : https://github.com/pareshgehlot/nodejs-stripe-payment 
; I hope it will be helpful to you

Comment: @MatthewArkin you can answer my question so I can mark it as answered :)

Comment: @gehlotparesh you should note there are some PCI issues with your code and I would not recommend using it, as it stands, in production.

Comment: @Matthew Arkin : Thanks for being frank and telling the facts, However I just did it as a part of my learning, still would like to thank you for the rectification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` is the whole token object but Stripe just wants the `id` of the token object, thus setting source to `req.body.id` should fix it.